# Unlocking old Sprint iPhone 4s

Tags: ios, iphone, unlock, cellular-carriers

I have an old Sprint iPhone 4s that hasn't been under contract for around a year now and I have a friend on T-Mobile whose contract doesn't end for another year. He still has a flip phone so I want to give him the old iPhone. Is there a way to unlock the iPhone if it is no longer under contract?

Answer (score 1):

Unlocking is trivial with carrier support.

Here is Apple's article on how to proceed technically once your carrier has unlocked the device:

- http://support.apple.com/kb/HT5014

We have a nice thread on this Sprint to T-Mobile shift here:

- [Getting an unlocked iPhone 4/4S to work on T-Mobile](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/27969/getting-an-unlocked-iphone-4-4s-to-work-on-t-mobile)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your account was in good standing while the phone was under contract with Sprint, you would have to call Sprint Customer Care to get it unlocked. See [Sprint clarifies iPhone 4S unlocking policy](http://www.macworld.com/article/1163003/sprint_clarifies_iphone_4s_unlocking_policy.html) on Macworld.

Sprint customer care representatives on its forums state that unlocking is done primarily for international use. Call Sprint World Wide on (888) 226-7212 to get it done.

Also see the following on the Sprint community forums:
[Unlock iPhone 4S](http://community.sprint.com/baw/thread/132351)
[i need my iphone 4s unlock](http://community.sprint.com/baw/thread/132667)

Answer (score -2):

In order to unlock - you will need to jailbreak it first. If you did want to jailbreak your iphone 4s as well,then jailbreak gives you to complete control to download whatever apps you want. That information is best for you that have an to unlock their iPhone.